# Passing the same interface as parameter in interface methods

Tags: go

I am trying to implement a diff logic using the interface implementation in Golang. I need to find the diff for different structs.

So I'm trying something like this

```
package main

import "fmt"

type foo interface {
    diff(f foo) bool
}

type baz struct {
    i int
}

func (b baz) diff(eb baz) bool {
    return b.i != eb.i
}

func main() {
    b1 := baz{1}
    b2 := baz{2}

    if b1.diff(b2) {
        fmt.Println("data is different")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("data is same")
    }
}
```

It is working fine. But I need to confirm whether Golang supports this type of interface implementation in which the method accepts the same interface.

Comment: *"I need to confirm whether Golang supports this type of interface implementation in which the method accepts the same interface."* -- It does, the fact that you didn't get a compiler error should be proof enough, no? Note, however, that `diff(eb baz) bool` does not implement `foo` because `baz` *is not* `foo` regardless of whether or not it implements `foo`. For `T` to implement `I`, `T`'s methods must match `I`'s methods **verbatim**.

Answer (score 0):

In golang it doesn't have OOP concept from it's core so it's doesn't have implement. Ref https://tour.golang.org/methods/10
so it will difference from other language when you implement interface it's mean your class will have all method that represent interface method
but for golang when you have struct that have the same method as method in interface then your struct's method will satisfy interface explicitly that way you can use struct's method.

If your struct have method more than interface method you still can use your method(that satisfy interface) when you call interface method.